# regular expressions: "at least one of the captures must match"

Tags: java, regex

Consider the following regular expression:

```
/^(A....)?(B..)?(C...)?$/
```

Is there a way to limit the regex in the way that "at least one of the captures must match"?

Actually I need this for java regular expressions. I could imagine, that it's not possible. Maybe with the more powerful perl regex machine?

Of course, I could post-process it, but maybe there is another way..

Comment: If you're using Java, why did you add the Perl tag?

Comment: I think there is no way: you have to post-process to make sure this rule is matched. In fact, I doubt that Perl have such a mechanism....

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: The Java and Perl regex engines are about equal in power.  Each has a couple of features that the other does not, but you are not anywhere close to any of those.

Comment: Can't you just use `^(?:(A....)|(B..)|(C...))$` or even simpler `^(?:A....|B..|C...)$`?

Comment: @stribizhev that doesn't quite work because it only matches *one*, not *at least one* (e.g. it doesn't match if both the `A` and `B` groups are present.

Comment: Why not `^((A....)|(B..)|(C...))$` - at least one (at most one, if not `...)+$`)

Comment: @JoopEggen, like stribizhev's, that permits only one of the alternatives.  Adding a `+` quantifer does not help, because the result matches many strings that the original does not.

Comment: @Anton harald -- you need to provide some explicit examples, and more details about your requirement.  Do you need an exact match of ONLY the captured groups, or can the source text simply contain one of the groups?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make sure that *something* matches with a look-ahead

```
/^(?=.)(A....)?(B..)?(C...)?$/
```

Comment: great answer! works perfectly. Slighlty better than the one before, since lookbehind is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this pattern:

```
^(A....)?(B..)?(C...)?(?<=.)$
```

The zero-width assertion at the end ensures that there is at least one character in the overall match, which will not be the case if none of the groups matches anything.

Answer (score 0):

RegEx match pattern:

`/apples|bananas|carrots/`

Source text:

`This allows apples or bananas or carrots to appear anywhere in the source text, confirming that the source contains at least of of the choices.`

See https://regex101.com/r/gZ1cW5/1

But, as I commented, it is not clear what you really want.  It's not clear if you need to know which one was matched.
You should always post example source text to be evaluated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it looked like it was clear, what I wanted, since I received very precise answers to my question.